# Conditional statements for custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have 2 template files , One template file is front-page.php and the other template is a custom one. Basically the code below is stating if it is front page then use this body class but if its anything else then use other body class. What I am trying to do is have my new template use the same body class as my front-page.php. I am having some issues making this occur. So basically,it needs to be "if front page or custom-template.php then use body class everything else "innerbody"

```
<?php if(w3c()){ ?><?php if(is_front_page() || is_page_template ('page-templates/front-page.php')){?><body> <?php } else{ ?><body id="innerbody"><?php } ?>
```

Comment: You don't use body class in the code you provided. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally used function for this is [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class), and is used typically within the `header.php` template in the HTML body tag. Default classes that this function add are based upon a particular page that is displayed, so that they themselves are the solution for most of the stuff.

You can add additional body classes by using the [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Adding_More_Classes) filter, add the following to the `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    // add custom class to the $classes array and return the $classes array
    if ( is_front_page() || is_page( 'page-slug' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'innerbody';
    }
    return $classes;
});
```

Now you can use [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) inside that function to test the conditions that must be met to in order to take the specific action, in this case to add additional classes to the body tag. I recommend that you check the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) documentation also, it is the first step towards understanding the concept of themes and templates in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another `is_page_template()` call to your `if()` function, and another OR (`||`) in your `if()`.

```
<?php if(w3c()){ ?>
        <?php if(is_front_page() || is_page_template ('custom-template.php') || is_page_template ('page-templates/front-page.php')){?>
            <body>
        <?php } else{ ?>
            <body id="innerbody">
        <?php } ?>
```